# Ramsey theorems for the naturals and for general infinite sets

Tags: logic, computability, ramsey-theory, reverse-math

In reverse mathematics and in recursion theory, the infinite Ramsey theorems are usually stated in terms of coloring of $[\Bbb N]^n$.  How do these (not) imply the Ramsey theorems for general infinite sets $X \subseteq \Bbb N$, in the metatheory, over RCA$_0$, or computability-theoretically?

A first try is to extend a coloring of $[X]^n$ to a coloring of $[\Bbb N]^n$ so that one can get an infinite homogeneous set for the former from the one for the latter.  I believe that, in order to do this, I should be careful not to introduce additional structures in the coloring of $\Bbb N \setminus X$.  But this is precisely what the Ramsey's theorem state is impossible, if $X$ is coinfinite!

Comment: I don't know reverse mathematics or recursion theory, but why can't you just use the order-preserving bijection $f:\mathbb N\to X$ to define a coloring of $[\mathbb N]^n$ which is isomophic to the given coloring of $X^n$?

Comment: @bof I can.   Thank you.

Comment: @bof That's exactly how it works in reverse mathematics - you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the order-preserving bijection $f:X\to\mathbb N$ to define a coloring of $[\mathbb N]^n$ which is isomorphic to the given coloring of $[X]^n.$ Namely, for $s\in[\mathbb N]^n,$ give $s$ the color originally assigned to $f^{-1}(s).$